# How to adjust the quality of a resized image in Python Imaging Library?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on PIL and need to know if the image quality can be adjusted while resizing or thumbnailing an image. From what I have known is the default quality is set to 85. Can this parameter be tweaked during resizing?

I am currently using the following code:

```
image = Image.open(filename)
image.thumbnail((x, y), img.ANTIALIAS)
```

The `ANTIALIAS` parameter presumably gives the best quality. I need to know if we can get more granularity on the quality option.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use PIL's `resize` method manually:

```
image = image.resize((x, y), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # LANCZOS as of Pillow 2.7
```

Followed by the save method

```
quality_val = 90
image.save(filename, 'JPEG', quality=quality_val)
```

Take a look at the source for [`models.py`](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/source/browse/trunk/photologue/models.py) from Photologue to see how they do it.

Comment: Thanks, thats just exactly what I was looking for...

Just an addition:
The quality option is a kwarg so has to be passed as quality=quality

Comment: Also note that if your original picture is `indexed`, in most cases it will increase the quality of the output if you convert it to `RGB` or `RGBA` before calling `.resize()`.

Comment: +1 for the quality option. But I don't get why `resize` would be better than `thumbnail`. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, there's no difference. I just checked the source, and `thumbnail` calls `resize`.

Comment: The two methods differ if the final size is not same aspect ratio of the inital one. `thumbnail` fits the final size leaving empty space. `resize` stretches the image. They work same way if aspect ratio is not changed.

Comment: Also they have different resampling method, but this can be changed.

Comment: From [the documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg): `quality`: The image quality, on a scale from 1 (worst) to 95 (best). The default is 75. Values above 95 should be avoided; 100 disables portions of the JPEG compression algorithm, and results in large files with hardly any gain in image quality.

Comment: How to reduce the quality without saving the image?

Answer (score 48):

ANTIALIAS is in no way comparable to the "85" quality level.  The ANTIALIAS parameter tells the thumbnail method what algorithm to use for resampling pixels from one size to another.  For example, if I have a 3x3 image that looks like this:

```
2 2 2
2 0 2
2 2 2
```

and I resize it to 2x2, one algorithm might give me:

```
2 2
2 2
```

because most of the pixels nearby are 2s, while another might give me:

```
1 1
1 1
```

in order to take into account the 0 in the middle.  But you still haven't begun to deal with compression, and won't until you save the image.  Which is to say that in thumbnailing, you aren't dealing with gradations of quality, but with discrete algorithms for resampling.  So no, you can't get finer control here.

If you save to a format with lossy compression, that's the place to specify levels of quality.

Answer (score 16):

Don't confuse rescaling and compression.

For the best quality you have to use both. See the following code:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(filename)
image.thumbnail((x, y), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save(filename, quality=100)
```

In this way I have very fine thumbs in my programs.

Comment: "The image quality, on a scale from 1 (worst) to 95 (best). The default is 75. Values above 95 should be avoided; 100 completely disables the JPEG quantization stage."

http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-jpeg.htm

Comment: @Izzad-DinRuhulessin The link seems broken. Maybe you could recite it.

Answer (score 1):

Antialias n set quality like 90

```
   img = img.resize((128,128),Image.ANTIALIAS)
   img.save(os.path.join(output_dir+'/'+x,newfile),"JPEG",quality=90)
```

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/resize-thousands-images-python

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve better quality is to do the downscaling in two steps. For example if your original image is 1200x1200 and you need to resize it to 64x64 pixels, then on the first step downscale it to somewhere in the middle of these two sizes:

1200x1200 -> 600x600 -> 64x64

Comment: This is only true if you use a poor downscaling filter.