# PIL: scale image while maintaing highest possible quality

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL to scale images that range anywhere from 600px wide to 2400px wide down to around 200px wide. I've already incorporated `Image.ANTIALIAS` and set `quality=95` to try and get the highest quality image possible.

However the scaled down images still have pretty poor quality compared to the originals.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
# Open the original image
fp = urllib.urlopen(image_path)
img = cStringIO.StringIO(fp.read())
im = Image.open(img)
im = im.convert('RGB')

# Resize the image
resized_image = ImageOps.fit(im, size, Image.ANTIALIAS) 

# Save the image
resized_image_object = cStringIO.StringIO()
resized_image.save(resized_image_object, image_type, quality=95)
```

What's the best way to scale an image along these ratios while preserving as much of the image quality as possible?

I should note that my primary goal is get the maximum quality image possible. I'm not really concerned with how efficient the process is time wise.

Comment: Can we see some examples? I.e., original image, a scaled-down image made with your script, and a scaled-down image made with Photoshop for comparison?

Comment: You are generally better off iterating through the pixel regions in the result image and see what area they map back to in the original image.  This is more important for rotation, but it might be relevant for fully arbitrary scaling as well.

Comment: The code you've shown is probably the best that PIL can do - you're converting to RGB and using ANTIALIAS. I've recently discovered that ANTIALIAS is actually the Lanczos3 algorithm which is considered pretty good. I'm curious to know what you find lacking in the result?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get results with the native resize options in PIL, you can manually calculate the resize pixel values by running them through your own resizing function. There are three main algorithms (that I know of) for resizing images:

- Nearest Neighbor
- Bilinear Interpolation
- Bicubic Interpolation

The last one will produce the highest quality image at the longest calculation time. To do this, imagine the pixel layout of the the smaller image, then scale it up to match the larger image and think about where the new pixel locations would be over the old ones. Then for each new pixel take the average value of the 16 nearest pixels (4x4 radius around it) and use that as its new value.

The resulting values for each of the pixels in the small image will be a smooth but clear resized version of the large image.

For further reading look here: [Wikipedia - Bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation)

Comment: PIL has all those built-in, BTW. However, `Image.ANTIALIAS` is the algorithm recommended for downsizing.

Comment: +1 thanks guys, yeah, I'm already using the Image.ANTIALIAS algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different approach. I'm not sure if this will help, but I did something similar a while back:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13211834/1339024

It may be that the original image on the urlpath is not that great quality to begin with. But if you want, try my script. I made it to shrink images in a given directory, but this portion could be of use:

```py
parentDir = "Some\\Path"
width = 200
height = 200
cdpi = 75
cquality = 95
a = Image.open(parentDir+'\\'+imgfile) # Change this to your url type
iw,ih = a.size
if iw > width or ih > height:
    pcw = width/float(iw)
    pch = height/float(ih)
    if pcw <= pch:
        LPC = pcw
    else:
        LPC = pch
    if 'gif' in imgfile:
        a = a.convert("RGB")#,dither=Image.NONE)
        a = a.resize((int(iw*LPC),int(ih*LPC)),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        a = a.convert("P", dither=Image.NONE, palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
        a.save(outputDir+"\\"+imgfile,dpi=(cdpi,cdpi), quality=cquality)
    else:
        a = a.resize((int(iw*LPC),int(ih*LPC)),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        a.save(outputDir+"\\"+imgfile,dpi=(cdpi,cdpi), quality=cquality)
```

Comment: *Sorry about the labeling, made this a while ago, and have completely forgotten what these acronymns stand for. I believe pcw and pch stand for PercentChange of dimension (although not really a percent change),and LPC is LowestPercentChange (ditto).

Comment: @rollingstone Let me know how it works. Also, if you're having trouble implementing this, feel free to let me know.