# Compress PNG image in Python using PIL

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-imaging-library

I have a python script recorded with Selenium Builder that takes the full browser screenshot of a webpage using the following:

```
fileName = "Screenshot1.png"
webDriverInstance.save_screenshot(fileName)
```

The file size is about 3.5 MB since it is a long, scrollable page and I need the full browser screenshot. I need a way to compress the saved screenshots, or save them as smaller file size PNG images so that I can attach and send several such screenshots in the same email using another Python script (with smtplib).

I tried this:

```
fileName = "Screenshot1.png"
foo = Image.open(fileName)
fileName2 = "C:\FullPath\CompressedImage.png"
foo.save(fileName2, "PNG", optimize = True)
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. Both files, Screenshot1.png and CompressedImage.png are of the same size (about 3.5 MB).

I tried several options with the save method but none of them seem to work. I do not get any errors when I run the script, but there is no decrease in the file size either.

```
foo.save(fileName2, "PNG", optimize = True, compress_level = 9)
foo.save(fileName2, "PNG", optimize = True, quality = 20)
```

I am using Python 2.7. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607468/how-to-reduce-the-image-file-size-using-pil

Comment: This worked. Thank you !

Comment: Wait... what's the difference between the link and what you were already doing?

Answer (score 8):

I see two options which you can both achieve using `PIL` library given for instance an RGB image.

1 – Reduce the image resolution (and therefore quality – you might not want that). Use the `Image.thumbnail()` or `Image.resize()` method provided by PIL.

2 – Reduce the color range of the image (the number of `colors` will affect file size accordingly). This is what many online converters will do.

```
img_path = "img.png"
img = Image.open(img_path)
img = img.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=256)
img.save("comp.png", optimize=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The PNG format only supports lossless compression, for which the compression ratio is usually limited and not freely adjustable.

If I am right, there is a variable parameter that tells the compressor to spend more or less time finding a better compression scheme. But without a guarantee to succeed.