# Is there an efficient way to compress a screenshot in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a lot of screenshots after selenium test runs, and I'd like to reduce size of screenshots to save disk space.
I tried to use PIL library next ways:

1. use image.thumbnail() method to resize image and as a result I've got few profit (like from 140kb to 120kb) and low quality of screenshot.
2. use image.save() method with "optimize=True" parameter and 1-2kb profit as result
3. also tried image.save() with low "quality" parameter and it seems to have no effect

And I tried compress image with some online service and I've got compress result from 140kb to 40kb and great quality of screenshot.
So my question - is there any library or way in Python to compress as well as any online service does?

Comment: What image file format are you using?

Comment: selenium takes png shots

Comment: then please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004067/compress-png-image-in-python-using-pil

Comment: Thanks! reducing color range did exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reducing colors range compressed image from 139kb to 40kb as I was looking for, thanks Daweo for link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71327798/13252674