# Not able to convert jpeg to pdf without getting a huge pdf

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a pdf of 6 megs and when I convert it to a set of jpeg images then convert it back to into pdf, the resulting pdf is 48 megs.  Even when I used the following code

```
from PIL import Image
for x in os.listdir(dir1):
    im = Image.open(f'{dir1}{x}')
    im.save(f'{dir2}/{x}', optimize=True, quality=60)
```

Which optimizes all of my jpeg images, I am only reducing the jpeg file size by 20% that is from about 400K to about 350K.  I am not getting the 5X reduction like this person is getting:

[How to reduce the image file size using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607468/how-to-reduce-the-image-file-size-using-pil)

The code I'm using to convert the pdf to jpg is the following

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as path:
    
    images_from_path = convert_from_path(filename, output_folder=path, first_page=0, fmt='jpg')

for e, page in enumerate(images_from_path):
 
    num = e + first_pg
    num = vgf.pad_numbers(num, 3)
    page.save(f"{dest}{long}{num}.jpg", fmt='jpg')
```

Comment: Depends on your images too. A completely black JPEG at 10240x4096 can be compressed to just a few kilobytes, but the more detail you add, the harder it is to compress without wrecking the picture.

Comment: well they are black and white pics

Comment: Can you use PNG format? Perhaps it can handle black and white images better.