# Python PIL, preserve quality when resizing and saving

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a large image, which I resize in PIL so that it is 250 pixels wide. This is the width that it will be shown on my website.

However, the resolution is really bad. I see that it has changed the dpi from 180 to 96. If I resize the image in a program like Windows Paint then it maintains the 180 dpi. This Paint-resized image looks a lot better on my website. (The paint-resized image is 40kb while the PIL resized image is 16kb)

How do I maintain the dpi (or set it to some max that looks good on websites)

I resize this using PIL:

```
image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save(filepath)
```

I have tried:

```
dpi = image.info['dpi']  # (180, 180)
image.save(filepath, dpi = dpi)
```

but it makes no difference. The dpi is 180, but the resolution is still bad. I'm guessing that the dpi needs to be set during resizing?

EDIT:

The issue seems to be the saving, not the resizing. Even if I start with the Paint-resized image (and therefore do not resize the image in PIL), it still saves it as the crappy quality 96 dpi (16kb) intead of keeping it as it is.

Comment: That's the solution I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Paint just ignores the DPI. But so do web browsers, unless you're specifically doing Retina-specific (or non-Apple-equivalent) CSS. If it's 250 pixels wide, and lay it out in a 250-pixel `img` tag, the DPI is irrelevant.

Comment: Something is different because the 40kb image looks way better than the 16kb image even though both are 250px wide.

Comment: @user984003: What format are you saving the file in? Is it JPG or something else lossy?

Comment: It starts out as jpg and that's what I save it as.

Comment: @user984003: Then that's almost certainly your problem, not the DPI.

Comment: So I should save it as what? png?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to the discussion with abarnert, I (he) realized that the issue was the saving, not the resizing.

And then I was able to find this, which solved the issue:

```
image_fullsize.save(filepath+name_fullsize, quality=95)
```

from here:
    [How to adjust the quality of a resized image in Python Imaging Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405602/how-to-adjust-the-quality-of-a-resized-image-in-python-imaging-library)

Comment: quality was the answer to me.

Comment: worked perfectly!

Comment: img.save('test.jpg', quality=100, subsampling=0)

https://jdhao.github.io/2019/07/20/pil_jpeg_image_quality/